# Integrate PhpStorm with Gitlab for managing tasks

Tags: phpstorm, gitlab, taskmanager

Is it possible to integrate Gitlab task manager to PhpStorm without any plugins? What about integrate it with plugins ?

I want to manage my team member's tasks inside PhpStorm and use Gitlab task manager.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can add GitLab server via Settings\Preferences | Tools | Tasks | Servers and work with tasks from it.
There are also several GitLab plugins available via Settings\Preferences | Plugins > Browse repositories that could add some additional actions.